# Taking const pmr::vector<>& not propagating allocator when using conditional operator with rvalue

Tags: c++, c++17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory_resource>

class SpecialMemoryResource : public std::pmr::memory_resource
{
public:
    void* do_allocate(std::size_t bytes, std::size_t alignment) override  { return nullptr; }
    void do_deallocate(void* p, std::size_t bytes, std::size_t alignment) override {}

    bool do_is_equal(const std::pmr::memory_resource& other) const noexcept override {
        return &other == this;
    }
};

static auto k_SpecialMemoryResource = SpecialMemoryResource{};

bool isUsingSpecialMemoryResource(const std::pmr::vector<int>& vec) {
    const bool usingSpecial{vec.get_allocator().resource() == &k_SpecialMemoryResource};
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << usingSpecial << std::endl;
    return usingSpecial;
}

void Func(const std::pmr::vector<int>& vec) {
    const bool LHS = true, RHS = false;
    const std::pmr::vector<int>& localLValRef{std::pmr::vector<int>{&k_SpecialMemoryResource}};

    isUsingSpecialMemoryResource(LHS? vec : localLValRef);
    isUsingSpecialMemoryResource(RHS? vec : localLValRef);
    isUsingSpecialMemoryResource(LHS? vec : std::pmr::vector<int>{&k_SpecialMemoryResource});
    isUsingSpecialMemoryResource(RHS? vec : std::pmr::vector<int>{&k_SpecialMemoryResource});
}

int main() {
    const auto specialVec = std::pmr::vector<int>{&k_SpecialMemoryResource};
    Func(specialVec);
}
```

Running the code above results in:

> ```
> true
> true
> false
> true
> ```

Why is the [polymorphic_allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator)'s [memory_resource](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/memory_resource) not propagated in the third case? My expectation here is that I'm just binding references and not constructing/converting any `std::pmr::vector`, so I see no reason by anything would change. But am I missing something in the [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other)'s type deduction that is triggering a `std::pmr::vector` [copy construction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that is not propagating the allocator?

> 6. Copy constructor. Constructs the container with the copy of the
>    contents of other, the allocator is obtained as if by calling
>    `std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::select_on_container_copy_construction(other.get_allocator()).`

Or something else? I'm not sure what's going on, and find the conditional operator's type deduction doc difficult to parse.

I'm compiling with clang10, `-std=c++20`:

> ```
> clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 
> Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
> Thread model: posix
> ```

Comment: `LHS? vec : std::pmr::vector<int>{&k_SpecialMemoryResource}` does require creating a temporary copy-constructed from `vec`. The expression must either be an lvalue or an rvalue, it can't be lvalue sometimes and rvalue other times, depending on the run-time values of the operands. So the rules for `?:` are such that, if one of the branches is an rvalue, then the whole expression is an rvalue, and a temporary is created as necessary. Now, why this copy doesn't propagate the resource, I'm not sure.

Comment: Ah. `polymorphic_allocator::select_on_container_copy_construction` [is documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator/select_on_container_copy_construction) to return a default-constructed `polymorphic_allocator`, and not propagate the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`true ? vec : std::pmr::vector<int>{&k_SpecialMemoryResource}` indeed creates a temporary object copy-initialized from `vec`:

> **[expr.cond]/2** If either the second or the third operand has type `void`... [doesn't apply]
> **3** Otherwise, if the second and third operand are glvalue bit-fields ... [doesn't apply]
> **4** Otherwise, if the second and third operand have different types ... or if both are glvalues ... [doesn't apply]
> **5** If the second and third operands are glvalues ... [doesn't apply]
>
> **[expr.cond]/6** Otherwise, the result is a prvalue...
> **[expr.cond]/7** Lvalue-to-rvalue ... standard conversions are performed
> on the second and third operands. After those conversions, one of the following shall hold:
> (7.1) — The second and third operands have the same type; the result is of that type and the result object is initialized using the selected operand.

Thus, lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is performed on `vec`:

> **[conv.lval]/3** The result of the conversion is determined according to the following rules:
> (3.2) — Otherwise, if `T` has a class type, the conversion copy-initializes the result object from the glvalue.

---

We must now look at the behavior of the copy constructor of `std::pmr::vector<T>`, which is an alias for `std::vector<T, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<T>>`. Turns out, the copy gets a default-constructed allocator; the memory resource is not propagated. Which is what you observe.

> **[container.requirements.general]/8** Unless otherwise specified, all containers defined in this clause obtain memory using an allocator... Copy constructors for these container types obtain an allocator by calling `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::select_on_container_copy_construction` on the allocator belonging to the container being copied.

> **[allocator.traits.members]/8** `static Alloc select_on_container_copy_construction(const Alloc& rhs);`
> *Returns:* `rhs.select_on_container_copy_construction()` if that expression is well-formed; otherwise, `rhs`.

> **[mem.poly.allocator.mem]/15** `polymorphic_allocator select_on_container_copy_construction() const;`
> *Returns:* `polymorphic_allocator()`.
> **16** [ *Note:* The memory resource is not propagated. *—end note* ]